# Twitter Login: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, oauth

This code is to authorize the login page from twitter and request token and secret token are stored in the yml db in config. Whenever I run this code, it gives the follwing error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

See the image and code below

http://s2.postimg.org/4wshzrwrd/err.png

```
 class TwitterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def login

oauth.set_callback_url("http://#{request.host}#{":#{request.port}" unless request.port == 80}/twitter/finalize")

session[:request_token] = oauth.request_token.token
session[:request_secret] = oauth.request_token.secret

redirect_url = oauth.request_token.authorize_url
redirect_url = "http://"+redirect_url unless redirect_url.match(/^http:\/\//)
redirect_to redirect_url
end

def finalize
end

private

def oauth
    @oauth ||= Twitter::OAuth.new(APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_key], APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_secret])
# @oauth ||= Twitter::Client.new(:consumer_key => APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_key], :consumer_secret => APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_secret])



end

end
```

Comment: Read the error you linked in that image. It says `Uninitialized constant Twitter::OAuth` ... Did you not include that module?

Comment: Seems like `APP_CONFIG[:twitter]` is `nil`. Could you please show how you retrieve this info?

Comment: Yes. You can view or download the code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/134v3yas6ze7q05/app.zip